# Could NOT find CURL (missing: CURL_LIBRARY CURL_INCLUDE_DIR) with CMAKE_C_COMPILER_RANLIB:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/gcc-ranlib

Tags: centos, yum

I follow the [installation facter](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/3.8/install_tarball.html#step-2-download-puppet-and-its-dependencies)

and I downloaded the latest version `3.9.6` `tar.gz` package.

[image]

but I get the below error:

```
[root@localhost release]# cmake ..
-- Could NOT find CURL (missing: CURL_LIBRARY CURL_INCLUDE_DIR)
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:69 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindLeatherman.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
  has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "Leatherman", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Leatherman" with
  any of the following names:

    LeathermanConfig.cmake
    leatherman-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Leatherman" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Leatherman_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Leatherman" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/tools/puppet/facter-3.9.6/release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
[root@localhost release]#
```

the `CMakeLists.txt:69` is:

```
CMAKE_C_COMPILER_RANLIB:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/gcc-ranlib
```

I have curl in my CentOS 7.2 server,

```
[root@localhost release]# curl --version
curl 7.29.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.29.0 NSS/3.36 zlib/1.2.7 libidn/1.28 libssh2/1.4.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz unix-sockets
```

and I have tried install `libcurl4-openssl-dev` but there is no package:

```
yum  install libcurl4-openssl-dev -y
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.aliyun.com
 * extras: mirrors.aliyun.com
 * updates: mirrors.aliyun.com
No package libcurl4-openssl-dev available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Answer (score 1):

Centos uses a different package name. The Debian/Ubuntu package name is `libcurl4-openssl-dev`. However, `libcurl-devel` on CentOS provides the same files and more. Try this instead:

```
sudo yum install libcurl-devel
```

Also, you can search for available packages like in this example:

```
yum search libcurl
```

[YUM COMMAND CHEAT SHEET](https://access.redhat.com/sites/default/files/attachments/rh_yum_cheatsheet_1214_jcs_print-1.pdf)